# Check if one table has other table related by id

Tags: mysql

I have User table where every user has entry and every User has entry in Profile table with user_id form User table,
How can I check if:

```
Select FROM table.users where(table profiles do not exist based od user_id )
```

I deleted manually some entry in Profile table and now I want find entry in User table which do not have entry in Profile table

Comment: You have a database called `table`? Is that not a little confusing?

Comment: Heum.. Maybe you're looking for something like LEFT JOIN (edit)

Comment: Something like? `select Id from Users where Id not in(select distinct userid from Profiles)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
LEFT JOIN profiles ON (users.id = profiles.user_id)
WHERE profiles.user_id IS NULL
```